# Cmake commands as macro arguments

Tags: cmake, macros

I want to use a CMake macro as a text replacement tool to call a command. This is something I am familiar with in C, but I am not sure if this is allowed in CMake.

what I want to be able to do:

```
MY_MACRO(
    MY_COMMAND(ARGS)
)
```

I have tried a few different variations on this general idea on how to implement this, but I am not sure it is possible.

```
MACRO(MY_MACRO)
    # do stuff
    ${ARGN} # Call MY_COMMAND
    # do stuff
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out based on this thread:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20800#note_951424

I haven't tested very thoroughly, but this is the gist at least:

```
MACRO(MY_MACRO)
    #stuff
    CMAKE_LANGUAGE(EVAL CODE ${ARGN})
    #stuff
ENDMACRO(MY_MACRO)
```